# JavaScript add events to newly created elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a loop that creates Html links and assign click events to them in the same loop. The click event seems to work only for the last element that the loop creates.

```
<div id="list">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    users = { 
        1 : { id : 1 },
        2 : { id : 2 },
        3 : { id : 3 },
        4 : { id : 4 }              
    };
    
    for (var index in users) {
        
        var user = users[index];
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += '<a href="" id="user-' + user.id + '">' + user.id + '</a>';
         
         var element = document.querySelector("#user-" + user.id);
         console.log(element);
         
         element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
             console.log(this);
             event.preventDefault();
         });
         
    }
</script>
```

Here only the last link is click-able. However if the links have already been created then all the event listeners will work.

```
<div id="list">
   <a href="#" id="user-1">1</a>        
   <a href="#" id="user-2">2</a>        
   <a href="#" id="user-3">3</a>        
   <a href="#" id="user-4">4</a> 
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    
    users = { 
        1 : { id : 1 },
        2 : { id : 2 },
        3 : { id : 3 },
        4 : { id : 4 }              
    };
    
    for (var index in users) {
        
         var user = users[index];
         var element = document.querySelector("#user-" + user.id);
         console.log(element);
         
         element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
             console.log(this);
             event.preventDefault();
         });
         
    }
</script>
```

This seems to work without any issues. Is there away to make sure that an event is attached to the element at creation?

Note: I don't want to use JS framework for this.
I know that this can be done easily using jQuery.

```
$( "body" ).on('click', "#user-" + user.id ,function(){});
```

Note:
The code I posted is a simple code I created on the fly to illustrate the problem. I am using a template engine that return a string, that's why I am using

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += '<a href="" id="user-' + user.id + '">' + user.id + '</a>';
```

Comment: You can implement event delegation, like jQuery's `.on()` without libraries quite easily: `document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', function(event){ console.log( event.target ); });`

Comment: But then I have to test for the event.target, check which link was clicked and then pass the link object to the call back to preserve the "this" object (What a pain). It's hard to believe that JavaScript is that retarded of the language. I can query an element but cannot assign it an event.

Comment: I have to do it your way it seems

Comment: No you don't. Your problem is in `.innerHTML` which breaks the DOM with every iteration, which means the previously added events are wiped out and you only have the listener attached to the very last element. Use DOM API to create and append these elements and everything will work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/HtxZb/ (but I'd still recommend the event delegation route).

Comment: The problem is that I have to use innerHtml because I am using a template engine that return a string. The code I posted is a simple code I created on the fly to illustrate the problem. I will just try to create a delegation.

Comment: @pawel if you post your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `.innerHTML` which breaks the DOM with every iteration, which means the previously added events are wiped out and you only have the listener attached to the very last element. You can use DOM API to create and append these elements and everything will work fine: jsfiddle.net/HtxZb

I would, however, recommend using event delegation. Without jQuery you can implement it like this:

```
document.getElementById('list')
    .addEventListener('click', function(event){ 
        var elem = event.target;
        console.log( elem );
        if( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "a" ){ // a link was clicked
            /* do something with link
               for example 
                switch( elem.id ){
                }
            */
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xhYS/):

```
<div id="list">
</div>

users = { 1 : { id : 1 },
    2 : { id : 2 },
    3 : { id : 3 },
    4 : { id : 4 } };

for (var index in users) {

    var user = users[index];

    var element = document.createElement("a");
    element.id = "user-" + user.id;
    element.innerHTML = "user-" + user.id;

    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(element);
    console.log(element);

    element.onclick = function(event){
        console.log(this);
        event.preventDefault();
    };
}
```

Comment: Just tried it. It does not work. Only the last link works. I initially had the same idea as you. But this does not seem to be the issue. The issue is when the function is assiigned to the onclick, the element does not seem exist yet.

Comment: I already knew that this was not the solution. Delegation is. But I was wondering if there is away implement delegation without the need to use event.target.

Comment: This works but it is not what I am looking. As I have pointed in the comment section that this is a simple example I created to illustrate the problem. I must use the innerHTML to create the links because in my real example I am using a JS template engine. I have pointed out in the question that the problem is attaching the events. Try your example again without the clasure and it will work too. innerHTML seems not to preserve the event listeners, that's my problem. Clasurs are used to preserve scoop.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to attach the `onclick` handler before appending to the DOM element.
This should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

users = { 
    1 : { id : 1 },
    2 : { id : 2 },
    3 : { id : 3 },
    4 : { id : 4 }              
};

for (var index in users) {

    var user = users[index];
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href='#';
    a.id = "user-" + user.id ;
    a.onclick = function(event){
         console.log(this);
         event.preventDefault();
     }
    a.innerHTML = user.id;
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(a);

}
</script>
```

Comment: I created a simple example to illustrate the problem. I want to create the content as string because in my real situation I am using a template engine to create the elements. Template engines return the template as a string. Thanks anyways.

Comment: so you're saying this is not the actual question

Comment: @thedethfox use two loops then. One to create the HTML, the second to add event listeners. Or delegate ;)

Comment: It's a question. because I did not know how to do it until pawel pointed out how in the comment section. I did know about Jquery's on function but I don't know how it works under the hood.